# YII module login

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет. `DefaultController` модуля наследуется от `ModuleController`. В `ModuleController` в правилах доступа (`accessRules`) прописано

```
array(
    'allow',
    'actions'=>array('login'),
    'users' =>array('?'),
),
```

после чего, незареганного пользователя он выкидывает в `login` дефолтного контроллера сайта (`site/login`). Почему и каким образом это происходит? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфигурации приложения для компонента user надо задать loginUrl.

Например, у меня конфигурация храниться в файл app_dir/protected/config/main.php:

```
'components'=>array(
  ...
  'user'=>array(
    ...
    'loginUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl(array('module_name/controller_name/action_name')),
    ...
  ),
  ...
),
```